# Convergence of $\lim_{K\rightarrow +\infty}(\sum_{k=1}^{K} a_k^2) / (\sum_{k=1}^{K} a_k)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Whether $(\sum_{k=1}^{K} a_k^2) / (\sum_{k=1}^{K} a_k)$ can converge to $0$ as $K\rightarrow \infty$ if $a_k > 0$, $a_k\rightarrow 0$ but $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \rightarrow +\infty$? If take $a_k = \frac{1}{k}$ it's right, but if take $a_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt k}$ it's not sure (I don't know whether it is true since it's $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$).

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you for your reminder. I'll edit my question. I am asking the first one.

Comment: @YuzhenFeng Ok, see Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\frac{1}{{\sqrt k }}}  = 2\sqrt K  + \mathcal{O}(1),\quad \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\frac{1}{k}}  = \log K + \mathcal{O}(1)
$$ as $K\to+\infty$.